# Create pop up box with more than 3 options?

Tags: android, android-layout

I know how to make the AlertDialog box with the 3 options.

What I want to do is after I click a button, a box will pop up with about 7 or 8 options, like buttons or a list of options.

What can I use to do that?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom dialog box.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html